# rectangle function undefined in octave

Tags: undefined, octave, rectangles

for some reason, neither the octave terminal, nor my editor recognizes the rectangle-function.
For example, when I try to get the documentation via the help command, I get this:
octave-3.2.4:41> help rectangle
error: help: `rectangle' not found

I'm sure it's an incredibly stupid error, but I just can't find it.
Everything else is working fine.

I appreciate any help!
Hannah

Comment: Please update your GNU Octave installation, we're at 3.8.

Comment: to be more specific, the function `rectangle` was added to Octave version  3.6.0 but if you're going to update, you might as well update to 3.8.1.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that this was the problem. For some reason, the latest version wasn't available in the Ubuntu software center, that is why I didn't have it installed.

Comment: you can use [Octave's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/stable) to update to 3.8.1 (easier and most recommended), you can build from source. Either way, you can get more details on Octave's wiki page for [Debian systems](http://wiki.octave.org/Ubuntu).